# Scrape info from popup window with Playwright in Python and store in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, async-await, playwright-python

I'm using Playwright in a Jupyter Notebook to obtain building construction years from a property appraiser's website. Some web pages, [like this one](https://www.pbcgov.org/papa/Asps/PropertyDetail/PropertyDetail.aspx?parcel=73414434010020070), have multiple buildings' data viewable only after the user clicks `View Building Details` partway down the page.

I can get Playwright to click the `View Building Details` button and click through to `Building 2`, `Building 3`, and `Building 4`.

**The issue** is that I can't extract the `Year Built` data underneath the `Structural Element for Building ###` table.

**The goal** is to have a script that will click the `View Building Details` button and cycle through Buildings 2 through *n* and collect each one's `Year Built` value.

I'm trying to use Pandas' `read_html` function to pull out the tables, but I'm open to other solutions.

This is what I have:

```
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import pandas as pd

playwright = await async_playwright().start()
browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless = False)
page = await browser.new_page()

## Go to PAPA property address

await page.goto("https://www.pbcgov.org/papa/Asps/PropertyDetail/PropertyDetail.aspx?parcel=73414434010020070")

x = await page.content() 

## Click text=View Building Details

await page.locator("text=View Building Details").click()

#######################################

## Click text=Building 2
await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("text=Building 2").click()
x2 = await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("html").inner_html()

## Click text=Building 3
await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("text=Building 3").click()
x3 = await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("html").inner_html()

## Click text=Building 4
await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("text=Building 4").click()
x4 = await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("html").inner_html()

x2s = pd.read_html(x2)
x3s = pd.read_html(x3)
x4s = pd.read_html(x4)

x2s[3] // When it works this is the table that I want
x3s[3]
x4s[3]
```

I think the issue has something to do with loading times. The script *kind of* works when each click to cycle through additional buildings is wrapped in a `try` and `except` block with instructions to wait for a certain selector. I copied the selector using Chrome's dev tools and tried both CSS selectors and relative xpaths. See example:

```
try:
    await page.wait_for_selector('//*[@id="frmPage"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'BUILDING 3: {e}')
```

I did try using `time.sleep` but the script still failed and didn't return the right info. The docs caution against using `time.sleep` anyway.

I tried included putting `await page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")` between each attempt.

Comment: One brilliant feature of Playwright is `playwright codegen` which will start an automated browser session, let you steer and generate the code as you go.  If you hover over an element it will give you its choice of selector, which may help in your case above.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  Try the df.iloc[row_start:row_finish,column_start:column_finish] command. It works for me.  It may also be a problem with the Jupyter notebook - style running of Playwright.  Save this into a file.py and run from the terminal in the correct directory: python file.py

I used asyncio to run Playwright, as I had a template script available, but you should get it working without it too, if you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import Playwright, async_playwright
import pandas as pd

async def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    page = await browser.new_page()
    ## Go to PAPA property address
    await page.goto("https://www.pbcgov.org/papa/Asps/PropertyDetail/PropertyDetail.aspx?parcel=73414434010020070")
    x = await page.content() #You're not using this, so you may as well remove this line.

    ## Click text=View Building Details
    await page.locator("text=View Building Details").click()
    #######################################

    ## Click text=Building 2
    await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("text=Building 2").click()
    x2 = await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("html").inner_html()

    ## Click text=Building 3
    await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("text=Building 3").click()
    x3 = await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("html").inner_html()

    ## Click text=Building 4
    await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("text=Building 4").click()
    x4 = await page.frame_locator("#MainContent_Iframe7").locator("html").inner_html()

    x2s = pd.read_html(x2)
    x3s = pd.read_html(x3)
    x4s = pd.read_html(x4)

    print(x2s[3].iloc[0:,0:]) # When it works this is the table that I want
    print(x3s[3].iloc[0:,0:])
    print(x4s[3].iloc[0:,0:])

    year_built_building_1 = x2s[3].iloc[3][2]
    year_built_building_2 = x3s[3].iloc[3][2]
    year_built_building_3 = x4s[3].iloc[3][2]
    
    print(year_built_building_1,year_built_building_2,year_built_building_3)


async def main(debug=True) -> None:
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        await run(playwright)

asyncio.run(main())
```

On my side it outputs:

```
                                     1                                   2
0   Structural Element for  Building 1  Structural Element for  Building 1
1                                  NaN                                 NaN
2                      Exterior Wall 1               CONCRETE BLOCK STUCCO
3                           Year Built                                2018
4                  Air Condition Desc.                                 NaN
5                            Heat Type                                NONE
6                            Heat Fuel                                NONE
7                            Bed Rooms                                 NaN
8                           Full Baths                                 NaN
9                           Half Baths                                   1
10                      Roof Structure           WOOD JOISTS, WOOD/COMPOSI
11                          Roof Cover           ALUMINUM/STEEL PANEL ENML
12                     Interior Wall 1                              STABLE
13                        Floor Type 1                         RUBBER TILE
14                             Stories                                   1
                                     1                                   2
0   Structural Element for  Building 1  Structural Element for  Building 1
1                                  NaN                                 NaN
2                      Exterior Wall 1               CONCRETE BLOCK STUCCO
3                           Year Built                                2018
4                  Air Condition Desc.                                 NaN
5                            Heat Type                                NONE
6                            Heat Fuel                                NONE
7                            Bed Rooms                                 NaN
8                           Full Baths                                 NaN
9                           Half Baths                                   1
10                      Roof Structure           WOOD JOISTS, WOOD/COMPOSI
11                          Roof Cover           ALUMINUM/STEEL PANEL ENML
12                     Interior Wall 1                              STABLE
13                        Floor Type 1                         RUBBER TILE
14                             Stories                                   1
                                     1                                   2
0   Structural Element for  Building 1  Structural Element for  Building 1
1                                  NaN                                 NaN
2                      Exterior Wall 1               CONCRETE BLOCK STUCCO
3                           Year Built                                2018
4                  Air Condition Desc.                                 NaN
5                            Heat Type                                NONE
6                            Heat Fuel                                NONE
7                            Bed Rooms                                 NaN
8                           Full Baths                                 NaN
9                           Half Baths                                   1
10                      Roof Structure           WOOD JOISTS, WOOD/COMPOSI
11                          Roof Cover           ALUMINUM/STEEL PANEL ENML
12                     Interior Wall 1                              STABLE
13                        Floor Type 1                         RUBBER TILE
14                             Stories                                   1
2018 2018 2018
```